# 2.82 Fluid friction?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm wondering if there's an option that deals with the fluid / effector **friction** in the new Mantaflow system - I can't seem to find one.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to the same thing, best results I've had so far are with the obstacle-fluid threshold setting at the bottom of the liquid sub-menu of the domain.